# Integral of $\int(4-2x)^\frac{1}{3}dx$

Tags: integration

I solved this integral then I did $\frac{d}{dx}$ of $F(x)$ and saw that it's not the same, so I did something wrong in my integration process. 
$$\int(4-2x)^\frac{1}{3}dx$$

What I did is $$F(x) =\frac{(4-2x)^\frac{4}{3}}{-2\times\frac{4}{3}} + C$$
Thanks!

Comment: the $-2$ should not be in the numerator. It should be in the denominator (i.e, you should divide by $-2$ the first term, not multiply)

Comment: Ahh I see. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
use this formula :$\displaystyle \int (ax+b)^n\,dx=\frac{(ax+b)^{n+1}}{a(n+1)}$

in your question $\displaystyle a=-2 , b=4,n=\frac{1}{3}$

so answer will be $\displaystyle \frac{3\cdot(4-2x)^\frac{4}{3}}{-8}$

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution, let $4-2x=u$, then $-2dx = du \implies  dx = \frac 1{-2}du$, thus the integral is 
$$\int \frac{u^{\frac{1}{3}}}{-2}du$$